# Making a sequential playlist of videos in python

Tags: python, opencv, psychopy

I'm trying to run a visual behaviour experiment where a whole heap of videos in a folder play one after another. I need to do this in python because I have a TTL pulse generator which I need to run at the start and end of each video.

I'm using cv2 and to try and play the videos but for reasons I can't figure out, I can't get them to play sequentially

Attached is my code

```
import cv2
import os
import random

videofolderPath = '/folderwithfiles'
videos = []
playlist = []
for file in os.listdir(videofolderPath):
  if file.lower().endswith(".mp4"):
    path=os.path.join('/folderwithfiles/',file)
    playlist.append(path)
    

random.shuffle(playlist)

for i in range (3):
  i += 1
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(playlist[i])
  print(playlist[i])

  while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q') or ret==False :
      cap.release()
      cv2.destroyAllWindows()
      break
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
  cap.release()
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The issue I'm having is I think they're all playing at once. When I press q I do see another video behind it but am struggling to get them to play one after another.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an error because you try to show the video before testing `if ret == False`.

Also, you should update `i` at the end of the loop as python indexing is zero based

The fix would look like this: (note that I changed the video folder path to test your code)

```
import cv2
import os
import random

videofolderPath = './videos'
videos = []
playlist = []
for file in os.listdir(videofolderPath):
    if file.lower().endswith(".mp4"):
        path = os.path.join(videofolderPath, file)
        playlist.append(path)

random.shuffle(playlist)

for i in range(3):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(playlist[i])
    print(playlist[i])

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        # REMOVE cv2.imshow(f'frame_{i}', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q') or ret == False:
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    i += 1 # UPDATE INDEX AT THE END
```

A better way of writing your code would be something like this:

```
import cv2
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    video_folder = "./videos"
    for video_name in os.listdir(video_folder):
        if not video_name.endswith(".mp4"):
            continue
        video_path = os.path.join(video_folder, video_name)

        video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

        while True:
            ret, frame = video.read()
            if not ret:
                break
            cv2.imshow("video", frame)
            cv2.waitKey(1)

        video.release()

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Also, I would recommend you to look at threading to load your video in "parallel" as it is very cpu intensive

Comment: there is **no need** for any threading. he wants to read/show them in order.